# outputting variable in the URL

Tags: coldfusion

I want to print my own dates in the form of variable in the URL:

I have the following url:

```
<cfset urladdress = "https://abc.xyz.com/start_date=2013-04-01&end_date=2014-04-22&data_type=123">
```

I have set my dates like the following:

```
<cfparam name="startdate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',-1,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
<cfparam name="enddate" default="#DateFormat(dateAdd('d',0,now()), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#">
```

And now, I am trying to print it like the following:

```
<cfset urladdress = "https://abc.xyz.com/start_date="<cfoutput>#startdate#</cfoutput>"&end_date="<cfoutput>#enddate#</cfoutput>"&data_type=123">
```

And I get following error:

```
 Invalid CFML construct found on line 19 at column 123.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

<

The CFML compiler was processing:

    < marks the beginning of a ColdFusion tag.Did you mean LT or LTE?
    A cfset tag beginning on line 19, column 2.
```

Do I need to use  URLEncoded Format Function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `<cfoutput>` inside a `<cfset>`

```
<cfset urladdress = 
  "https://abc.xyz.com/start_date=#startdate#&end_date=#enddate#&data_type=123">
```

You should use [encodeForURL()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForURL) (cf10+ only) or [urlEncodedFormat()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/URLEncodedFormat) around the variables to be safe.

If you want to use `encodeForURL()` in CF9, check out: 
https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport

Comment: I tried using `urlEncodedFormat()` but got result like the following when I dumped urladdress : `2014%2D04%2D22&end_date=2014%2D04%2D23`.

Comment: @user3558091 it's fine, whoever receiving it will have it decoded to what you'd expect.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: And I think since I am using Coldfusion 9, using `encodeForURL()` is givign an error :`Variable ENCODEFORURL is undefined. `

Comment: @user3558091 read my answer.  `encodeForURL()` is CF10+ only, unless you use https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport which will get you `encodeForURL()` in CF9.  They both do very similar thing, but `encodeForURL()` is newer and covers more cases than the older `urlEncodedFormat()` but it's usually good enough.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I got that.

Comment: Not only do you not need cfoutput inside cfset, but you can't nest cfml tags like that.